# Can a home widget have a Context?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-context

In an activity it's (usually) easy to get the Context.

What if I am working with a home widget class?
These are classes that extends AppWidgetProvider, which don't contain a Context!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An instance of Context is passed to all the methods in [AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) for you to use.

Comment: This is true; nevertheless, the question still holds if you are adding listeners which are called from the onPostExecute of AsyncTask for instance. In this case, you do not have a context in the methods signature. What do you do?

Comment: Just in case you still have this question, I got around it by passing the context to the AsyncTask and returning it in the onPostExecute. Not good-looking, but it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't access [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) like me, here's where you can get context in app widget:

Android provides context in `onReceive` method in widget class.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```